# Could not load file or assembly Common.Logging

Tags: common.logging

I wrote class library to support writing a log using NLog and log4net with Common.Logging. When I test with project I get error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

FlushLog:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Common.Logging, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Source/Hits2000/Web-Applications/WinhitsWebApi/WinhitsWebApi.ApiService/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Source\Hits2000\Web-Applications\WinhitsWebApi\WinhitsWebApi.ApiService\bin
Calling assembly : Common.Logging.Log4Net1211, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Source\Hits2000\Web-Applications\WinhitsWebApi\WinhitsWebApi.ApiService\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Common.Logging, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f19f3155/f95cde26/Common.Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f19f3155/f95cde26/Common.Logging/Common.Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Source/Hits2000/Web-Applications/WinhitsWebApi/WinhitsWebApi.ApiService/bin/Common.Logging.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar exception in my .Net program. I had up and downgraded some nuget packages, which gave me the error and a mild headache.

I changed this in my App.config

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.0.0" newVersion="3.4.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

To this

```
      <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.0" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

The version number had changed due to the nuget upgrade and didn't revert during the downgrade.